# SCRIPT87:Invalid Argument for IE 9,8,7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have the following set of code for a link button click in my ASP.net website.

```
string url = "Display_Mail.aspx?cust=" + custname + "&env=" + environment;
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PopupWindow", "<script language='javascript'>window.open('" + url + "', 'Display Mail', 'width=1350px,height=1400px,left=50px,top=50px,resizable=yes,scrollbars=1')</script>");
```

The above code works fine in Chrome,IE11,Fiefox but doesnt work for IE9 and lesser versions. It gives Script87: invalid argument error. Kindly help in this as mostly the website will be used in IE9 only.

Comment: Have a quick look on http://modernizr.com/

May be this can help you

Comment: @RahulRJ this is not done in HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: But asp.Net translates your code into javsscript. Your are calling javascript there, so Modernizr could very well help you.